# Concatenate fields in a csv file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a csv file with 20 fields: v1:v20. Is there any way to add another field after v5 which would be the concatenation of fields 2 to 5? For example, let's say the file header is:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v5, v7,...
a,  b,  c,  d,  e,  f,  g,....
```

I want it to look like this:

```
v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, new.field, v5, v7,...
a,  b,  c,  d,  e,   bcde,     f,  g,...
```

Comment: awk, sed, perl/php/python, etc... lots of ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
gawk -F ' *, *' -v OFS=',' '
{
    $6 = (NR==1 ? "new.field," : $2 $3 $4 $5 ",") $6
    print
}' input.csv
```

---

#### result:

```
v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,new.field,v5,v7,...
a,b,c,d,e,bcde,f,g,....
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
 sed 's/,/\n,/5;h;s/\n.*//;s/[, ]//g;G;s/\([^\n]*\)\n\([^\n]*\)\n/\2, \1/' file
```